# What is the source for "1000 raka'at during Shahri Ramadan"?

Tags: salat, sunnah, ramadan

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

**Where is it written that one is highly recommended to pray 1000 raka'as during Shahri Ramadan?**

I got it from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlJ3H6e1Vxg) and I couldn't find the source (Sunni or Shia).

**I'd like also to know how it should be prayed - distribution of these 1000 raka'as across the Shahri Ramadan.**

Comment: It is stated in different shi'a sources like [Was'il a-Shi'a](http://www.tahqiq.ir/Archive/513121) and elsewhere [see](http://qadatona.org/%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A/%D9%85%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1_%D9%88%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%B9%D8%A9/1942_%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D9%84%D9%81-%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1-%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%B6%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%88%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%D8%A7)

Comment: @Medi1Saif, don't you think this is where those 20 raka'as of Taraweeh come from? Explanation to the question you posted answer yesterday.

Comment: No because there are also narratives from 'Ali confirming the practice of 20 raka'a as a congregation as mentioned by al-Bayhaqi further the prophet himself lead taraweeh some nights.